# Release a Maven POM without expanding a variable

Tags: maven, release, javac

I've got a dependency on tools.jar in my project, which is a javac plugin. It can be configured to be run in a Maven build. So there's a maven plugin to enable a javac plugin.
This can be done by following the Maven FAQ: 
http://maven.apache.org/general.html#tools-jar-dependency
includes

`<systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>`

The problem is that the mvn release pom expands all variables, so when I've released my maven plugin, it refers to a hardcoded jdk path from the machine where the release was performed, rather than a variable to resolve it at runtime on the client machine.

That obviously causes my Maven plugin to fail to include tools.jar on the classpath.

I can't find any way to convince the maven release plugin to leave this variable in the output. Any ideas?

Bug reference: https://code.google.com/p/error-prone/issues/detail?id=18